# Android 4.4.2, colorAccent is not working for radiobuttons in dialog

Tags: android, colors, dialog

I can't understand where is my mistake.
There is my style

```
 <style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

Dialog's text and button's text are colored, but radiobuttons in my dialog are still black. Why does accennColor work for buttons's text and does not work for radiobutton ?

this is code for dialog create

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_choose_refresh_period));

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(cs, mCurrentSelectedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
        })

                // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_caption_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_caption_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel

                    }
                });

        mDialog = builder.create();//AlertDialog dialog; create like this outside onClick
        mDialog.show();
```